# Push Notifications With Firebase Cloud Messaging in Next Js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, push-notification

I'm trying to setup Firebase Cloud Messaging in Next Js project to do I add following files

One in `/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-messaging.js");

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "A.............KU0",
    authDomain: "ad......f.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "a.......f",
    storageBucket: "ad......m",
    messagingSenderId: "6.....0",
    appId: "1:63....331",
    measurementId: "G........Z"
  };
  
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
    );
    const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
    const notificationOptions = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: payload.notification.image,
    };
    
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });
```

2nd one in `/helper/firebase.js`:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "A.............KU0",
    authDomain: "ad......f.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "a.......f",
    storageBucket: "ad......m",
    messagingSenderId: "6.....0",
    appId: "1:63....331",
    measurementId: "G........Z"
  };

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export let messaging

if (process.browser) {                       
    // because I'm getting error "Navigator not defined"
    messaging = getMessaging(app)
};

export const VAPID_KEY = "BGP.....................A"
```

/helper/pushNotification.js

```
import { getToken } from "firebase/messaging";
import { VAPID_KEY, messaging } from "./firebase";

export const requestNotificationPermission = async () =>  {
    if ('Notification' in window) {
            const permission = await Notification.requestPermission()
            
            if (permission === 'granted') {
                console.log('Notification permission granted.');

                const token = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: VAPID_KEY })
                console.log('+++ token', token);
        
            } else if (permission === "denied") {
                alert('permission === "denied"')
            }
    }
}
```

/navbar.js

```
useEffect(() => {
    requestNotificationPermission()
}, [])
```

I'm getting this error

> Caught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.20.0/firebase-app.js' failed to load.
>
> at http://localhost:3006/firebase-messaging-sw.js:1:1
> (anonymous) @ firebase-messaging-sw.js:1

Any suggestions on how to resolve this and documentation to implement properly?

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in your `firebase.js` file

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getMessaging } from "firebase/messaging";

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "A......s",
   authDomain: "m...........a",
   projectId: "o.............g",
   storageBucket: "t.......m",
   messagingSenderId: "1...........",
   appId: "2............0",
   measurementId: ".........."
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = typeof window !== "undefined" ? getMessaging(app) : null;

export default messaging;
```

Comment: Nice! `typeof window !== "undefined"` prevented **FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source.**